# How to change a header text with the return of a function in HTML and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, web-deployment

I wanna calculate the mean and show the answer to the user after he click the calculate button.
I want to change the header called Result with the return of Calculate_Mean function which is the mean var, but It doesn't work with me and I can't figure what is going wrong, any help ?

```js
function Calculate_Mean() {
            var str = document.getElementById("Num").value;
            var arr = str.split(",");
            var count = arr.length;
            var sum;
    
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
              sum += arr[i];
            }
    
            var mean = sum / count;
    
            return mean;
 }
```

```html
<header>
          <h1> Statistical Website </h1>
          <button class="HomeButton" onclick="javascript:window.location.href='HomePage.html'"> Home </button>
        </header>
        <div id="banner">
          <form action="Script URL" method="GET|POST">
            <label>
              <h1> Enter the data set </h1> </label>
            <br>
            <textarea name="Num" rows="10" cols="30" autofocus> </textarea>
            <br>
            <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById ( 'Result' ).value = Calculate_Mean ()"> Calculate </button>
            <label>
              <h1> The result </h1> </label>
            <label>
              <h1 id="Result">  </h1> </label>
          </form>
        </div>
```

Comment: I would recommend replacing the h1 elements you are writing the result to with a more semantic element, such as a readonly input perhaps.

Comment: see my answer @Hwang Hee Ra _ Gogo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problems are:

1. You've used a `int` which is not part of `javascript`.

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {  
        ^---------- Should be `var` not `int`
   ```
2. You are trying to set `value` of a h1 element whereas you should set `innerHTML`

   ```
   document.getElementById('Result').value=....
                                  ^------------ should be `innerHTML` not `value`
   ```
3. You need to set `id` first to the `<textarea>` before trying to get it.

   ```
   <textarea name="Num"..... ---> should be id="Num"
   ```
4. You actually need to `parse` `integer` from the `array` of `string` before adding.

   ```
   var arr = str.split(","); ---> this line will return array of string.
   ....
   sum += arr[i]; ----> 'arr[i]' will give string and the result will be concatenated not added.
   ```

**Working solution**

**The HTML should look like this inside your `<form>` tag**

```
<textarea id="Num" rows="10" cols="30" autofocus> </textarea> <!-- Set 'id' not 'name' -->
<br>
<button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById("Result").innerHTML=Calculate_Mean();"> Calculate </button>
<label>
    <h1> The result </h1> 
</label>
<label>
    <h1 id="Result">  </h1>
</label>
```

**The function should look like this:**

```
function Calculate_Mean() {
    var str = document.getElementById("Num").value;
    var arr = str.split(","); // Will return array of string
    var count = arr.length;
    var sum=0;
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) { // You had 'int' instead of 'var'
        sum += parseInt(arr[i]); // Need to parse integer before adding
    }
    var mean = sum / count;
    return mean;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple issues in your code.

1. remove `int` its not js keyword. Use `var` instead.
2. instead of `value` use `innerHTML`. `value` is used for `input` elements
3. `Num`was defined as `name` it should(also) be `id`
4. use `parseInt()` to read array values as numbers. Also assigned initial value of `sum` to 0. More info about [parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

```js
function Calculate_Mean() {
        var str = document.getElementById("Num").value;
        var arr = str.split(",");
        var count = arr.length;
        var sum=0;

        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
          sum += parseInt(arr[i]);
        }

        var mean = sum / count;

        return mean;
      }
```

```html
<div id="banner">
      <form action="Script URL" method="GET|POST">
        <label>
          <h1> Enter the data set </h1> </label>
        <br>
        <textarea id="Num" rows="2" cols="30" autofocus> </textarea>
        <br>
        <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById ( 'Result' ).innerHTML = Calculate_Mean ()"> Calculate </button>
        <label>
          <h1> The result </h1> </label>
        <label>
          <h1 id="Result">  </h1> </label>
      </form>
    </div>
```

[jsbin demo](http://jsbin.com/jafujipoco/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: @Feathercrown click on the vote count you will see a downvote mate. Its rude to downvote without commenting about the reason.

Comment: Well I know that it's rude. The problem was I don't have access to that feature yet, and the votes were at 0. I guess I assumed too quickly....

Comment: May I suggest to add the radix to parseInt?

Comment: @AndFisher Hmm tnx. Added a doc link for `parseInt`. Let OP take it up as an exercise

Answer (score 0):

So we have a function `getMean()` it just needs to be passed the string e.g. "100,25,30" and it will return the result to the result h1. In this case the string im passing is the value of the textarea.

```
<button type="button" onclick= "getMean(document.getElementById('data').value)" >
```

to make this work i have also given the text area an id so it can be found with `getElementById()`

```
<textarea id="data">
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/km6uowq4/4/

```
        <header>
            <h1 > Statistical Website </h1>
            <button class="HomeButton" onclick="javascript:window.location.href='HomePage.html'"> Home </button>
        </header>
        <div id = "banner">
            <form action="Script URL" method="GET|POST">
                <label>
                    <h1> Enter the data set </h1>
                </label>
                <br>
                <textarea id="data" name="Num" rows="10" cols="30" autofocus>  </textarea>
                <br>
                <button type="button" onclick= "getMean(document.getElementById('data').value)" > Calculate </button>
                <label>
                    <h1 > The result </h1>
                </label>
                <label>
                    <h1 id = "Result">  </h1>
                </label>
            </form>
        </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

      function getMean(csv_string){
        var arr = csv_string.split(',');
        var total = 0;
        for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
          total = total + parseInt(arr[i],10);
        }
        var avg = total / arr.length; 
        document.getElementById("Result").innerHTML=avg;
      }

    </script>
```

Comment: that is not what the user meant

Comment: Why is it not?? You enter a series of numbers in the text area, hit the calculate button and the avg is calculated. whats wrong?

Comment: because the user wants to populate the `h1` with the `return` from the function `Calculate_Mean()` and your answer does not explain about it. and also your answer doesn't  explain anything that is wrong with the user code....

Comment: I have added explanation for the changes and returning the result to the h1. Better?